# How do you install a certificate to the Perl certificate store? 401 unauthorized

Tags: perl, ssl, ssl-certificate

How do you install a certificate to the Perl certificate store? I am getting the following error: `401 Unauthorized: Peer Certificate not verified.`

Is there a way to install the certificate the same way I would in Internet Explorer?

Comment: The what? Can you include a link?

Comment: moorecats got the idea from http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#KeyManagement, http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html

Answer (score 1):

[Set `HTTPS_CA_DIR`](http://p3rl.org/Crypt::SSLeay#ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES) to the directory containing the certificates. That's your store.